# copy cells down to next date and repeat

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I have dates in a column.
Each date is separated by 8 cells, these 8 cells are empty.
I am looking to fill the 8 empty cells with the first date
Upon reaching the next date i am looking to empty the next 8 vacant cells with the next date this then repeats till the last date is reached after which the following 8 empty cells are filled with the last date.

I dont think my question has been clear enough as i dont have the right answer yet

```
05/06/2015





06/06/2015






07/06/2015
```

should turn into

```
05/06/2015
05/06/2015
05/06/2015
05/06/2015
05/06/2015
05/06/2015
05/06/2015
05/06/2015
05/06/2015
06/06/2015
06/06/2015
06/06/2015
06/06/2015
06/06/2015
06/06/2015
06/06/2015
06/06/2015
06/06/2015
07/06/2015
07/06/2015
07/06/2015
07/06/2015
07/06/2015
07/06/2015
07/06/2015
07/06/2015
07/06/2015
```

This is the output i get from whytheq quickandfun method

```
05/07/2015
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
06/07/2015
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
07/07/2015
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
08/07/2015
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
09/07/2015
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
10/07/2015
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
11/07/2015
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
12/07/2015
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
13/07/2015
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
14/07/2015
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
15/07/2015
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
16/07/2015
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
17/07/2015
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
18/07/2015
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
19/07/2015
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
20/07/2015
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
21/07/2015
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
22/07/2015
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
23/07/2015
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
24/07/2015
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
25/07/2015
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
26/07/2015
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
27/07/2015
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
28/07/2015
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
29/07/2015
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
30/07/2015
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
31/07/2015
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
01/08/2015
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
00/01/1900
```

I also try changing the formula to

```
.Value = "=R[-1]C1"
```

SOLVED Answer below

```
lastRow1 = Sheets(myValue).Cells(Sheets(myValue).Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 7

For r = 2 To lastRow1
If Sheets(myValue).Cells(r, 2) = vbNullString Then
Sheets(myValue).Cells(r, 2) = Sheets(myValue).Cells(r, 2).Offset(-1, 0)

End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very pretty:

```
Sub eightAtATime()

dim colLetter as string
colLetter = "A"

Dim r As Integer
With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
   r = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End With

Do Until r < 1
    Range(colLetter  & r + 1 & ":" & colLetter  & r + 8) = Range(colLetter & r)
    r = r - 9
Loop

End Sub
```

Although something like the following is more fun and will fill the gaps whether 8 cells or not: although it assumes to fill 8 after the last cell:

```
Sub quickAndFun()

Dim lastRow As Integer
With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
   lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End With

With Range("A1:A" & lastRow + 8).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    .Value = "=R[-1]C1"
End With

End Sub
```

If the first cell is `B3` then try this:

```
Sub quickAndFun()

Dim lastRow As Integer
With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
   lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
End With

With Range("B3:B" & lastRow + 8).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    .Value = "=R[-1]C2" '<<<<now ok as it need to reference Column 2
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, you may want to look at my question which is now more clearer

Comment: @MrAssistance what is wrong with my answer, or the answer supplied by Maciej Los?

Comment: it doesnt appear to fill down like the reworded question, it just fills the first 8 blank cells and then all the other 8 blank cells are filled with 00/01/1900

Comment: @MrAssistance none of the three code snippets in the two answers work?

Comment: no they dont, have you seen my revised clarity on the question

Comment: @MrAssistance which column do you have the data in? What cell address are the first and second dates in?

Comment: first is B3 next is B12

Comment: @MrAssistance I changed the second solution to adjust for the top cell being B3 - hopefully getting warm now!

Comment: still not working i changed the vba to get the last row of column B to lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("B3").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count otherwise because of the gaps between the dates it doesnt get the last row. I am going to print my output in the main question in a minute

Comment: @MrAssistance my mewthod of working out lastRow is textbook...you should not need to change it

Comment: @MrAssistance - my error - please alter the C1 to C2 so the line of code is this: `.Value = "=R[-1]C2`

Comment: so this is the formula so far Sub quickAndFun()

Dim lastRow As Integer
With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
   lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
End With

With Range("B3:B" & lastRow + 8).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    .Value = "=R[-1]C2"
End With

End Sub                                                                                                                It still doesnt seem to work, by saying R[-1] isnt this referring to the cell which is one cell to the left of the one with dates?

Comment: @MrAssistance I've just edited the third code snippet - it is tested and works. `R[-1] ` means the row above.

Comment: this is very strange when i double click on the first date under first date cell, it refers to =$A4, the cell to the left

Comment: I gave you some credit for the help and direction :) See the answer in the question

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the work:

```
Dim wsh As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer, sCol As String
Dim cd Date, dd As Date

'column name which stores dates
sCol = "A"
cd = Date 'get current date
'Replace "Sheet1" with proper sheet name
Set wsh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
'starting row
i = 1 'if the first date is in 1. row
'get first date
dd = CDate(wsh.Range(sCol & i))
'till the date from cell is less then current date 
Do While dd<cd
    'till the next cell is empty
    Do While wsh.Range(sCol & i+1)=""
        wsh.Range(sCol & i) = dd
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    'get next date
    dd = CDate(wsh.Range(sCol & i))
Loop

'here add another loop, you have to define condition to recognize last empty cell - as whytheq mentioned in the comment to the my answer

Set wsh = Nothing
```

**Note:** *this code is not limited to 8 empty cells in a row!*

Comment: how about after the very last non empty cell? you will need to make some sort of assumption on how many cells to populate.

Comment: Yeah. It's OP's job ;)

Comment: Hello, you may want to look at my question which is now more clearer

Comment: @MrAssistance, No, it isn't more cleaner. Please, read whytheq comments. We don't know how to recognize last non empty cell.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Cheers, Maciej